# Sorting the items in the flatList. FlatList item doesn't update when I setState()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of products that is rendered in a Flatlist.

However I have a toggle button that toggles the display of this list. That is, when true, it shows the items at the lowest price, and when false, it shows the original list.

The problem is that when I press the toggle button the first time, it changes its state to true and organizes the list by price. But when I press it again it changes the state to false, but it keeps showing the list organized by price.

I've tried everything to make this switch, but I can't. Can someone help me by showing me where it's wrong?

My code:

```
    import Products from '../../produtos';

    export default () => {
      const [toggleFilter, setToggleFilter] = useState(toggleFilter);

      useEffect(() => {
        setToggleFilter(false)
      }, [])

      const toggleOrdem = () => {
        setToggleFilter(!toggleFilter)
      }

      return (
        <ProductList>

          <Header />
          <Button title="toggle" onPress={toggleOrdem} />

          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={toggleFilter ? Products.sort((a, b) => a.precoFinal - b.precoFinal) : Products}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Product data={item} />} />

        </ProductList >
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> data={toggleFilter ? Products.sort((a, b) => a.precoFinal - b.precoFinal) : Products}

Sorting an array will mutate the existing array. So if `toggleFilter` is true you are permanently changing what's in `Products`, then rendering it. When you flip `toggleFilter` to false, you use `Products` as it is, but due to the previous renders it is now a sorted array.

You will need to copy the array before sorting it:

```
export default () => {
  const [toggleFilter, setToggleFilter] = useState(toggleFilter);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToggleFilter(false);
  }, []);

  const toggleOrdem = () => {
    setToggleFilter(!toggleFilter);
  };

  const sortedArray = toggleFilter
    ? [...Products].sort((a, b) => a.precoFinal - b.precoFinal)
    : Products;

  return (
    <ProductList>
      <Header />
      <Button title="toggle" onPress={toggleOrdem} />

      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={sortedArray}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Product data={item} />}
      />
    </ProductList>
  );
};
```

For performance reasons, you may want to memoize the sorting instead of sorting every time you render. That can be done with useMemo this:

```
const sortedArray = useMemo(() => {
  return toggleFilter
    ? [...Products].sort((a, b) => a.precoFinal - b.precoFinal)
    : Products;
}, [Products, toggleFilter]);
```

---

P.S, This effect is very strange:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setToggleFilter(false)
}, [])
```

If you want the toggle to start as false, then delete the effect and initialize the state with `const [toggleFilter, setToggleFilter] = useState(false);`